# Array brodcasting in numba with parallel

Tags: python, numpy, optimization, numba, array-broadcasting

I'm trying to do a Monte Carlo simulation faster by using numba and numpy.
Numba'0.45.1' and Numpy '1.16.4'
However, I do have an error when I use the parallel option with the following code :

```py
@njit
def foo():
    clock = np.array([1,4,5,7,11,15,19])
    detector = np.array([2,3,6,10,13,20])
    test = np.expand_dims(clock,1)
    test2 = np.expand_dims(detector,0)
    return -test + test2
```

Works fine, but

```py
@njit(parallel=True)
def foo():
    clock = np.array([1,4,5,7,11,15,19])
    detector = np.array([2,3,6,10,13,20])
    test = np.expand_dims(clock,1)
    test2 = np.expand_dims(detector,0)
    return -test + test2
```

Raises the following error "AssertionError: Sizes of test, test2 do not match on..."

Do you have any idea to fix that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

We at a minimum, i dont think numba can take lists for literals.  Try np.array((1,4,5,7,11,15,19)), etc (parents instead of solid brackets)